# Deriving a cryptographic PRNG from a publicly random sequence

Tags: random-number-generator, pseudo-random-generator, randomness

Consider a model of computation where we have a public oracle that provides access to a random sequence $R$. Given an index $i$ the oracle returns either 0 or 1, with the responses being deterministic, but the response for $i$ independent of $i+1$. Intuitively you can think of the oracle as providing access to "shared randomness", where e.g. it flips a coin and caches the result of flip $i$.

Consider defining a PRNG as follows: given a seed index $s$, on consecutive runs of the PRNG seeded with $s$ we simply output $R[s], R[s+1], etc.$.

Does this PRNG have a polytime algorithm to differentiate its output from "true randomness" (assuming of course the adversary does not know the seed $s$). My intuition is that an adversary can only do so by determining the seed $s$, and to do so he must effectively perform a substring search for the observed inputs within $R$. Since we can only have a match at index $s$, determining the seed must take at least $O(s)$. But the seed itself is encoded in $\log S$ bits, so an algorithm that takes $O(s)$ is only in exptime, and hence wouldn't be able to differentiate in polytime.

Comment: *Sounds* reasonable to me. There is of course the assumption that the PRNG is not broken. As an aside, I would not compare a single bit output of a PRNG with a coin flip, but yeah, that doesn't influence the question otherwise. My biggest issue is the index; does a TRNG have a memory? But that's probably more a question to a student advisor or a prof as it is mostly about the capabilities of the oracle.

Comment: Hint: if $s$ is $k$-bit and the PRNG's expansion factor is $p(k)$, compute as a function of $k$ an upper bound of the probability that a query made to $R$ by an algorithm is for an input that's one of those effectively used by the PRNG. Use this to find an upper bound of the advantage an algorithm may give as a function of $k$ and the number $n$ of queries it makes.

Comment: Actually, there are real world PRNGs that can be viewed in this way; for example, the HASH_DRBG from NIST SP 800-90A